# To what extent is postmodernism an attempt to nullify our biological tendencies?

Tags: postmodernism

Postmodernism is an intellectual stance or mode of discourse defined by an attitude of scepticism toward what it considers as the grand narratives and ideologies of modernism, as well as opposition to epistemic certainty and the stability of meaning. It opposes the capitalist doctrine in an attempt to create equity within society with respect to outcome. It is also an attempt to nullify human's innate tendency to make judgments about anything so to make defunct the idea of social hierarchies and inequality. However, it is truly possible to create such a society (amending something so biologically fundamental) without there being an impacting consequence? Historically, those political philosophy that have been implemented that least reflect  innate human behavioural tendency created devastating effects. So how much of the utopian idea that postmodernism presents is actually a net-positive in the final analysis?

Comment: This sounds like an oversimplification/reading incomprehension of postmodernism, along with some propagandizing for biological essentialism, so, sadly, VTC.

Comment: @KristianBerry I'd say a solid read on the question, but this forum is the perfect place to take a question that skirts philosophical discourse in the land of politics, and draw out the finer philosophical distinctions required to claim some semblance of critical thinking, one of the primary purposes of philosophical discourse. :D Thanks for taking the time to answer it.

Comment: Which post modern utopian idea are you asking about?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know a million things about postmodernism, but according to what research I have done so far, there is nothing absolutely intrinsic to postmodernism that means opposing capitalism (at least in general; I suppose specific forms of capitalism might be subject to such opposition). I'm also unsure what the link between capitalism and elitism (understanding the latter as egalitarianism's foil) is supposed to be; economic inequality can translate into political inequality, granted, but it is logically possible for everyone to be in the same economic bracket even if people's finances are distributed by the free market (if consumption averages out and no monopolies form, or even if monopolies form and everyone goes along with it).

More importantly, though:

> However, it is truly possible to create such a society (amending something so biologically fundamental) without there being an impacting consequence? Historically, those political philosophy that have been implemented that least reflect innate human behavioural tendency created devastating effects.

Supposing that egalitarianism is opposed to elitism and that elitism is "natural" for *some* people does not, and from a physicalist point of view perhaps *cannot*, rule out egalitarianism being "natural" for *other* people. Pedophilia might be ingrained in some but I would hope that we do not therefore seek to cater to the whims of pedophiles. (On another note, it is also possible that some of the philosophical justifications for some forms of capitalism are barely distinguishable from some philosophical justifications for pedophilia, but I digress.) So elitism-*vs.*-egalitarianism is not a battle between "human nature" and "utopian idealism," but a battle between two kinds of "human nature." Too much can be made of Hume's is/ought gap, but if one's metaethics means trying to leap across the gap instead of building a stable bridge between them, I expect such a leap to fall short, as it does here.

And historiographically, it is hard for me to believe that Soviet or Khmer Rouge ideology (for example) were so murderous on account of their professed egalitarianism; it's hard for a dictatorial police state to lack elites, the dictator and their police being the elites in those cases, after all. And at any rate, supposedly more "natural" tendencies in ideology can also be caught up in regimes with devastating consequences, e.g. Nazism. But would it be historically accurate to critique Nazism on grounds of its traditionalistic elitism? The history of ideas is important but sometimes mountains are made of molehills and this seems like an example of that geographical allegory.

Comment: The Khmer Rouge specifically murdered millions of people for the crime of being upper class and tried to force everyone else into the same class. Regardless of the fact that there were effectively still upper class people (the soldiers who did the killing), they all claimed to be egalitarian, and their murders were justified by that goal. The connection is less blatant in Russia and China, but those mass murders were also justified in part by the need to achieve a classless society.

Comment: Also, I believe you are misunderstanding @Mike's point about hierarchy. It isn't that some people naturally prefer elitism, it is that societies naturally form hierarchies. If you create a classless society, a hierarchy will spontaneously develop (this has been proven over and over in communes, HOAs, high schools, and other semi-isolated societies), and it requires brutal suppression to keep it down. And of course, the people who do the brutal suppression are essentially the elites because they are the ones deciding how everyone else will live.

Comment: The strictly class-based component of Khmer Rouge democide was certainly not in the millions; intraparty purges, ethnic hostility, and initial de-urbanization (which itself alone cost ~200,000 lives IIRC), although admixed with class-theoretic ideology, did not target people solely on grounds of being upper class. The hundreds of thousands of peasants (best up-to-date figure I'm familiar with is around 500,000) worked to death under Angkar's slave labor regime would have tended to be lower class as such, too. Moreover, plenty of lower-tier cadres inherited trauma from [cont]

Comment: [cont] having to survive the well over 2,000,000 tons of bombs the US dropped on the country, and we know full well how such trauma can motivate future killers (including at least some serial killers). ::: Respecting spontaneous hierarchies, that's very well and all, but spontaneous anti-hierarchies constantly emerge, too, and I don't see that there is anything less "biologically grounded" about brutally suppressing hierarchies than supporting them.

Comment: So, "Egalitarianism has devastating consequences," specifically mass democides in communist bloc states (or the like), is just as much political pseudoscience as, "Racism has devastating consequences," seeing as there was a lot more involved in e.g. Nazi ideology than mere racism,

Comment: @DavidGudeman - Marxist thinkers generally aren't "egalitarian" in the sense of saying we must abolish all hierarchies, their target is classes specifically based on roles in production (those who own means of production vs. those who're paid to make products using them). See for example Engels opposing any call for "equality" beyond a change in material class relations at https://www.marxists.org/archive/marx/works/1877/anti-duhring/ch08.htm or Lenin making a similar point dismissing vague desires for "human equality" at https://www.marxists.org/archive/lenin/works/1914/mar/11.htm

Comment: The Khmer Rouge deliberately murdered all doctors, all teachers, and others in that social class. You are probably right that it was not in the millions, but that is hardly a significant point. They also worked to death a lot of peasants (and probably deliberately to entrench their control) but that also is not a counter to the claim that their anti-hierarchy stances was the specific reason for many murders.

Comment: As to Marxist thinkers, I made no general claims about Marxism, only about specific Communist governments. For that matter, the question was not about Marxism but about Postmodernism, and I made no claims about Postmodernism either.

Comment: @DavidGudeman - I understood this comment of yours to be a general criticism of the idea of eliminating "class" in the communist sense: *"If you create a classless society, a hierarchy will spontaneously develop ... and it requires brutal suppression to keep it down."* Were you only talking about the Khmer Rouge's particular concept of classlessness, not about attempts to create a classless society more generally? Russia and China's brutality was not a matter of wanting to suppress "hierarchy" in general, and only sometimes was it about class (as with Stalin's persecution of 'kulaks')

Comment: IIRC nationalism and pseudoscience were the predominant factors in the severity of the general slavery regimen in "Democratic Kampuchea." They wanted the country to be "self-sufficient," esp. vs. Vietnam (whom they despised to the point of genocide) and would make laborers design agricultural systems without taking into account elementary facts like the normal laws of gravity (vs. irrigation flow).

Comment: That latter example (going off my hazy memory) was something like making the farmers try to have the water flow uphill, and then when this obviously didn't work, they killed the farmers for "treason."

Comment: No, I wasn't referring to the Marxist ideal of a classless society; I was referring back to the question. The question itself does seem to assume a connection between Communist revolutions and Postmodernism--a link which I did not endorse because it is controversial and I'm not familiar enough with the topic to have an opinion (although in practice, it seems that most Postmodernists admire at least some Communist revolutionaries and mass murderers, so it is not far-fetched to assume a connection).

Answer (score 0):

### Answer

I concur with others that [post-modernism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postmodernism) is a broad umbrella, and that one simply can't characterize post-modernism as a movement to nullify biological truths. However, it is fair to say that post-modernism does question a lot of epistemological assumptions, and in it's extreme form, does seem to attack [empiricism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empiricism) itself. There is a post-modernistic doctrine that Stephen Pinker in [*The Blank Slate*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Blank_Slate) calls the Standard Social Science Model (SSSM). From page 16:

> The doctrine of the Blank Slate became entrenched in intellectual life in a form that has been called the Standard Social Science Model or social construction. The model is now second nature to people and few are aware of the history behind it.

Under the SSSM, there is a tendency to deny certain biological realities when it comes to the human mind and the human body. For instance, it has become very controversial to claim that there are [IQ differences between different "racial categories"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_and_intelligence), whatever that may be. At the intersection of biology, psychology, and politics, therefore, there are political efforts that might be seen as drawing parallels to [Lysenkoism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lysenkoism): that is, putting dogma and ideology before scientific practice.

Another topic that frequently makes the national news in the US is the question of whether it is fair for a [transgender woman to compete with cisgender women](https://www.theguardian.com/sport/2022/mar/23/ron-desantis-lia-thomas-trans-swimmer-ncaa-title-florida). It is a [false equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_equivalence) to claim that a transgender female body is biologically identical to a cisgender female body as it is unequivocally a scientific truth that there are undeniable [differences in the biology of men and women](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/29224088/). To claim that there are statistical differences of central measure between male and female bodies is a far cry from judging a person who is intersex or preventing them from being included in society, but often radical readings of human "equality" cast a pall over [empirical evidence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_evidence).

So, does post-modernism attempt to deny biological truth? Not really, but there are some post-modernist interpretations of science particularly among [social constructionism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_constructionism) that do seem to place a premium on normative sociological projects over positivist scientific claims. And these academic positions are often held up as [strawmen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straw_man) in contemporary political debates by dogmatic ideologues who create debates where none need be made. Generally, these sorts of positions are accompanied with a very poor understanding of the various sciences involved.